# What's pratical use of Derivate function calculus?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I would like to know whats the pratical use of derivate calculus? Or what it means?

If you can give some pratical example I'll be grateful.

**Eg.:**

I can use an definite integral to know area of a function knowing the expression of the function and the limits.

Know how to solve exercises make no sense if i cant imagine the real purpose and the objective meaning.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe here: http://www.teach-nology.com/teachers/subject_matter/math/calculus/                                                                                               http://www.ijee.ie/articles/Vol18-1/Ijee1262.pdf                                                                                             http://www.intmath.com/applications-differentiation/applications-of-differentiation-intro.php?PageSpeed=noscript

Comment: Because I *simply do not understand* what exactly you are asking for. Your question is very general, the answers given do not satisfy you, for given practical applications you then ask *why to use the derivative*. Look at the links which everybody can find and then maybe you can ask more specific questions.

Comment: Also [What do we mean by derivative of a function? What does it tell?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/938004/what-do-we-mean-by-derivative-of-a-function-what-does-it-tell)

Comment: @MJD, you completely right. The accepted answer is what my mind needed for. Thanks

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Copying my answer from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/938004/what-do-we-mean-by-derivative-of-a-function-what-does-it-tell/938021#938021)]

The derivative function says how fast the original function is changing at each point.  **If $f(t)$ is the position** of a particle or a rocket ship at each time $t$, then **the derivative $f'(t)$ is the speed** of the particle or the rocket ship at time $t$.

Consider as an example $f(t) = -5t^2 + 20t$.  Suppose this describes the height of a rocket above the ground at time $t$.  This curve is a downward-facing parabola with $f(0) = f(4) = 0$ and the peak of the parabola at $f(2) = 20$:

[image: parabola]

At $t=0$ we have $f(t) = 0$ and the rocket is on the ground.   The rocket goes up, quickly at first, then more slowly, until at $t=2$ it stops going up and starts to come down, slowly at first, then more quickly as time goes by, until it hits the ground again at $t=4$.

> What if you want to know the speed of the rocket?  **That is the derivative**, $$f'(t) = -10 t+20.$$

[image: parabola with derivative]

The derivative is the blue line in the picture.  **It represents the upward speed of the rocket at each point**. 
When $t=0$, the derivative has the value $20$, representing a fast upward motion.  When $t=1$, the upward speed has decreased to $10$.  When $t=2$, the rocket has reached the peak of its flight and has stopped going up and is about to come back down.  $f'(t) = 0$, meaning that the rocket has no motion at this instant.  Then at $t=3$ the derivative is $-10$, which represents a downward motion, and at $t=4$ when the rocket hits the ground its downward motion is twice as fast, since $f(4) = -20$.

Answer (score 2):

it was originally invented to calculate the trajectory of planets.

More generally, almost all physical laws describing how a system evolves are naturally expressed in term of derivatives. To compute the evolution of a system according to these laws, you need derivate calculus...

Comment: I know the history @Denis, and the usage (well, since i was born i have seen this on formulas, and where other guys decide use it). I wonna take the same base as the same guy who express : vel = dS/st

Answer (score 2):

There are a variety of applications especially in physics.

Suppose you know the force that acts on a particle with mass $m$ as a function of time, i.e. $F = F(t)$. Suppose you furthermore know that at $t = 0$, the velocity of the particle is given by $v_0$. It can be shown that

\begin{align*}
v(t) = v_0 + \int_0^t \frac{F(t^\prime)}{m} \mathrm{d} t^\prime
\end{align*}

where $v(t)$ denotes the velocity of the particle at time $t$ for $t \geq 0$.

Comment: My question that @hick: Why use derivate on this formula? I can memorize the formula but i wonna understand why to use.

Comment: I used an integral in this formula which is the opposite of a derivative. Alternatively: suppose you know the velocity of the particle as a function of time. The acceleration is per definition $a = \frac{\mathrm{d} v}{\mathrm{d} t}$. As the force acting on the particle is given by $F(t) = m a(t)$, we have $F(t) = m \frac{\mathrm{d} v}{\mathrm{d} t}$.

Comment: Thanks again @Hick. But a insist bro, my problem is not know the formulas, but understand why is the formula as it is. I know how to get the aceleration, but why use derivate when we have a variation on time.

Comment: The time derivative of the velocity gives you the rate of change of the velocity at a given time $t$. We call that the acceleration.

Comment: Hum... I'm getting sarted to understand. Thnks again @hick

Answer (score 0):

One practical use: Approximate ugly functions with nice ones. In fact, we like Lines, they are simple. The equation of a line is just

$$ Ax + By = C $$

Where $A,B,C$ are numbers. This is a nice function. Sometimes you may encounter functions like this one:

$$ f(x) = \sin ( e^{x^2} )\cdot e^{\arctan x} + x^8 - \ln x $$

$f$ is a horrible function. Calculus then help us. Derivative help us because we can approximate this $f(x)$ in a vicinity of a point $(x_0,y_0)$ where $f$ would make sense with a line, in fact explicitly given by

$$ \mathcal{L}(x) = y_0 + f'(x_0)(x-x_0)$$